# Prawn - how to generalize the common things in the pdf document into a separate module for code re-usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, prawn

I am using the Rails Prawn to generate pdf files. Now that i am able to generate pdf with all necessary things that i need(eg. table, header, footer, logo, borders etc...). Now I need to use the common things(header, foooter, borders) in a method inside separate module and call this method from my original program?

My original program:
travel_report.rb
module TravelReport

include Header
  def self.generate(start_ts, end_ts, format_type, obu_ids, interval)
    Prawn::Document.generate("public/test.pdf") do

## Borders

```
page_count.times do |i|
go_to_page(i+1)
Header.border
end
```

## Header and Boundary Lines

```
page_count.times do |i|
   go_to_page(i+1)
ask = "public/ashok.jpg"
    image ask, :at => [15, 750], :width => 120
    alert = "public/alert.jpg"
    image alert, :at => [410, 740], :width => 120
  end
```

## footer

```
 page_count.times do |i|
  go_to_page(i+1)
  lazy_bounding_box([bounds.left+30, bounds.bottom + 20], :width => 100) {
    text "Bypass Report"
   }.draw
  end
end
```

Separate Module for Borders
module Header
    #class Cheader < Prawn::Document::BoundingBox
    #include Prawn
    def self.border

```
      pdf = Prawn::Document.new
      pdf.bounding_box([5, 705], :width => 540, :height => 680) do
         pdf.stroke_bounds
        end

end
#end
```

end

This code doesnt creates any border... Any idea how to create separate module for this????

Answer (score 1):

```
#create a separate module

#program



include HeaderFooter
Prawn::Document.generate("public/test.pdf") do |pdf|
pdf.page_count.times do |i|
        pdf.go_to_page(i+1)
        HeaderFooter.border(pdf)      
        #render :partial => 'header', :locals => {:ppdf => pdf}
      end

#Header and Boundary Lines      
      pdf.page_count.times do |i|
        pdf.go_to_page(i+1)
          HeaderFooter.image(pdf)
      end
#footer
      pdf.page_count.times do |i|
       pdf.go_to_page(i+1)
        HeaderFooter.footer(pdf)
      end
    end 




create a module to define the methods(header_footer.rb)
module HeaderFooter
    #Method for border creation in pdf
    def self.border(ppdf)
       ppdf.bounding_box([5, 705], :width => 540, :height => 680) do
       ppdf.stroke_bounds
      end
    end
    #method to create the logos in the pdf
    def self.image(ppdf)
      ask = "public/ashok.jpg"
      ppdf.image ask, :at => [15, 750], :width => 120
      alert = "public/alert.jpg"
      ppdf.image alert, :at => [410, 740], :width => 120
    end
    #method to print footer text in the pdf
    def self.footer(ppdf)
      ppdf.lazy_bounding_box([ppdf.bounds.left+30, ppdf.bounds.bottom + 20], :width => 100) {
      ppdf.text "Bypass Report"
       }.draw
    end

end
```

This works fine...